# Kendo Grid filterMenuInit.checkSource.view() empty in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

With a Kendo Grid defined in ASP.NET, with columns set as multi filterable

```
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(True))
```

I have defined the filterMenuInit event like so:

```
.Events(ev => ev.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
```

Using the canonical js example for sorting the entries in a filter dropdown on a Kendo Grid,

```
function filterMenuInit(e) {
        var filterMultiCheck = this.thead.find("[data-field=" + e.field + "]").data("kendoFilterMultiCheck")
        filterMultiCheck.container.empty();
        filterMultiCheck.checkSource.sort({ field: e.field, dir: "asc" });
        filterMultiCheck.checkSource.data(filterMultiCheck.checkSource.view().toJSON());
        filterMultiCheck.createCheckBoxes();

    }
```

I have encountered the following issue - `filterMultiCheck.checkSource.view()` is always empty, causing the `.toJSON()` call to fail.

A grid defined totally in js (sadly NOT an option with this particular grid), within the same environment (Kendo Tab on Kendo Window) does not have this issue.

Has anyone any helpful clues?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be an option for you, but setting `ServerOperation` to `false` in the `DataSource` solved this for me.

```
.Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
.DataSource(d => d
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Read(...)
)
```